# $\lim_{x\to0}\,(a^x+b^x-c^x)^{\frac1x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Given $a>b>c>0$, calculate$\displaystyle\,\,\lim_{x\to0}\,(a^x+b^x-c^x)^{\frac1x}\,$

I tried doing some algebraic manipulations and squeeze it, but couldn't get much further.

Comment: i think this Limit is infinity

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner If I place numbers instead of parameters, wolfram gives a number as a result.

Comment: Use L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: no also Wolfram Alpha gives an other answer

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: For $b=c$, it's constantly $a$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \begin{align} 
\color{blue}{L} &= \lim_{x\to0}\left(a^x+b^x-c^x\right)^{\frac1x} \\[3mm] 
\color{red}{\log{L}} &= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(a^x+b^x-c^x\right)}{x}=\frac{0}{0} \qquad\left\{\log\left(a^0+b^0-c^0\right)=\log(1)\right\} \\[3mm] 
&= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left[\,\log\left(a^x+b^x-c^x\right)\,\right]}{\frac{d}{dx}\left[\,x\,\right]} \\[3mm] 
&= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^x\log{a}+b^x\log{b}-c^x\log{c}}{a^x+b^x-c^x} \\[3mm] 
&= \log{a}+\log{b}-\log{c}=\color{red}{\log{\frac{a\,b}{c}}} \quad\Rightarrow\, \color{blue}{L=\frac{a\,b}{c}}
\end{align} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for L'Hopital. Let $f(x) = a^x+b^x-c^x.$ If we apply $\ln$ to our expression, we get

$$\tag 1 \frac{\ln f(x)}{x} = \frac{\ln f(x)-\ln f(0)}{x-0}.$$

By definition of the derivative, $(1) \to (\ln f)'(0)$ as $x\to 0.$ Thus the limit of $(1)$ equals

$$\frac{f'(0)}{f(0)}  = \frac{\ln a + \ln b - \ln c}{1} = \ln (ab/c).$$

Exponentiating back gives $ab/c$ for the original limit.

Answer (score 0):

write your term in the form $$e^{\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(a^x+b^x-c^x)}{x}}$$
and use L'Hospital
distinguish two cases:
$x$ tends to $0^+$ and $x$ tends to $0^-$

Comment: Oh I see it now. So the answer is: $e^{ln\left(a\right)+ln\left(b\right)-ln\left(c\right)}$?

Comment: no the Limit for $x$ tends to $$0$$ doesn't exists see my answer above

Comment: The numerator doesn't tend to 0, you can't apply L'hospital

Comment: and when $x$ tends to $$ 0^_$$ in this case the Limit is zero

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Ignore my last comment, the numerator does tend to 0 but you mistyped $-c^x$ as $c^x$

Comment: no Problem errare humanum est

Comment: I still don't understand though. Your proof looks perfect but a plot suggests that the limit is not 0 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+(4%5Ex%2B3%5Ex-1.5%5Ex)%5E(1%2Fx)+as+x+tends+to+0 . Also, a series expansion about $x=0$ suggests that the limit is $ab/c$, I'm not sure it this expansion is valid though. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+of+(a%5Ex%2Bb%5Ex-c%5Ex)%5E(1%2Fx)+at+x%3D0

Comment: with L'Hospital we get $$\frac{ab}{c}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Isn't that equivalent to my result?

Comment: i have not seen your result sorry

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner In the first comment to your answer.

Comment: The exponent is so tiny!!!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}(a^x+b^x-c^x)^\frac{1}{x}=[1^\infty]=\exp\lim_{x\to 0}(a^x+b^x-c^x-1)\frac{1}{x}\boxed=\\(a^x+b^x-c^x-1)\frac{1}{x}=(a^x-c^x+b^x-1)\frac{1}{x}=c^x\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^x-1}{x}+\frac{b^x-1}{x}\\ \boxed =\exp \lim_{x\to 0}\left(c^x\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)^x-1}{x}+\frac{b^x-1}{x} \right)=\exp\left(\ln\frac{a}{c}+\ln b\right)=\exp\left( \ln \frac{ab}{c} \right)=e^\frac{ab}{c}$$